# Get bitmap orientation without using ExifInterface

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, exif

I need to figure out how to get the orientation from a bitmap. Thing is - images aren't always present on the device, so i cant use the ExifInterface to get the orientation info.
Somehow it always shows the bitmap in landscape, and the length and width attribute does not help me very much.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this without the ExifInterface?

I know i could store the orientation as an attribute in the database, but if there was another way - id prefer that.

Thanks in advance

edited:
I should add - the bitmaps gets downloaded from a site as a byte array, so it can get presented as a preview to the enduser on the device, before he actually decides to download it. Hopes this makes more sense

Comment: If the image is not on the device, what does your app have to do with the image?

Comment: Its a preview - for an image that can be downloaded.

Comment: Well, if the preview is not on the device, what is your app doing with the preview? Are you downloading that? If so, download it and use `ExifInterface` to check the orientation.

Comment: I know i can download it, and use the ExifInterface to get the orientation - but id like the preview to present the image, as it is.. in portrait or landscape. We are talking a whole lot of images, so the enduser should not have to download each and every one to see how it actually looks like.

Comment: oh - the preview IS on the device..

Comment: If the preview is on the device, use `ExifInterface` to examine the preview. Note that some image-loading libraries, like Picasso, handle this automatically (at least IIRC).

Comment: The preview is a bitmap.. Im pretty sure you cant use the ExifInterface to get the orientation info from a bitmap. Or am i wrong?

Comment: Well, where did the `Bitmap` come from? If it came from a file, examine the file. If it came from some other sort of stream, there are other EXIF parsers that handle that. If it came from a download, download the data to a file, examine it with `ExifInterface`, then read it in with `BitmapFactory`. And if it came from somewhere else, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I download the bitmap from a server as a byte array. The way it gets to be on the server, is because other users uploads images from their devices. After they upload the image - and the bitmap as a byte array - other users gets the bitmaps, and are presented with the option of downloading the entire image. So yea - guess im out of luck,

Comment: "I download the bitmap from a server as a byte array" -- if that `byte[]` is JPEG data, you can either write to a file and use `ExifInterface`, or you can wrap it in a stream and use [code like this](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/tree/master/src/com/android/mms/exif) to get at the EXIF data.

Comment: Ty. I'll try this - you may add suggestion as an answer, and ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reading EXIF headers, if you have JPEG data. Your choices are:

- Use [the `ExifInterface` from the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html), though this will require you to get the JPEG data into a file
- Use some other, more flexible EXIF parsing code, such as [this stuff from the AOSP Mms app](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/tree/master/src/com/android/mms/exif), which can handle streams and `byte[]` (see the `ExifInterface` in that directory and its set of `readExif()` methods)

In your case, you may encounter some problems:

- It is possible that the preview lacks the EXIF headers, depending on how the preview image was created. If that is the case, and you control the preview-creation process, you may be able to fix that server-side.
- This only works if your preview images are JPEGs. If they are in other formats (e.g., PNG), the EXIF headers will be lost. Again, if that is the case, you might address this server-side, such as having the preview generator rotate the image properly based on the EXIF header of the original.

If you do not have the `Orientation` EXIF header, and you do not control the server, you are pretty much doomed.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use my [metadata-extractor](https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) library which will read lots of kinds of metadata from multiple image types and is very efficient at doing so.

```
Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(stream);
```